# How to get data from array of references in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i have array of references [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVr8G.png);
and Collection lessons [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGK7K.png)
i am trying to get data from references that is in lessons array from collection Lessons

i have been trying solution that i have found but it works not as i expected
also i tried something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfdI.png)

Comment: Please edit your question so that any code is included in the question using the available text formatting tools. This will often facilitate a faster response and lead to better search results.

Comment: forEach doesn't await async functions within, you can use for..of or generate an array of promises with map.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop